# I can't get data from a website using beautiful soup(python)

Tags: python-3.x

i have a problem. I am trying to create a web scraping script using python that gets the titles and the links from the articles. The link i want to get all the data is https://ec.europa.eu/commission/presscorner/home/en . The problem is that when i run the code, i don't get anything. Why is that? Here is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

#url_1 = "https://ec.europa.eu/info/news_en?pages=159399#news-block"
url_2 = "https://ec.europa.eu/commission/presscorner/home/en"
    
links = [url_2]

for i in links:

    site = i
    page = requests.get(site).text
    doc = bs(page, "html.parser")
        
    # if site == url_1:

    #     h3 = doc.find_all("h3", class_="listing__title")
    
    #     for b in h3:
    #         title = b.text
    #         link = b.find_all("a")[0]["href"]
    #         if(link[0:5] != "https"): 
    #             link = "https://ec.europa.eu" + link
    #         print(title)
    #         print(link)
    #         print()

    if site == url_2:

        ul = doc.find_all("li", class_="ecl-list-item")
        for d in ul:
            title_2 = d.text
            link_2 = d.find_all("a")[0]["href"]
            if(link_2[0:5] != "https"):
                link_2 = "https://ec.europa.eu" + link_2
            print(title_2)
            print(link_2)
            print()
```

(I am also want to get data from another url(the url i have on the script) but from that link, i get all the data i want).

Comment: The reason is that in the second url the links are generated by javascript code, so they are not visible to BeautifulSoup, which only parse HTML. You should use other packages. I would suggest Selenium or PhantomJS, but don't know if they are still supported.

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint after the line page = requests... and you will see the data you pull. The webpage is loading most of its contents via javascript. That's why you're not able to scrape any data.

You can either use Selenium or a proxy service that can render javascript- but these are paid services.